# ASCII to Base32

Tags: vb.net, ascii, base32

I am working at making what 10 characters go into a text box in my vb project convert into Base32. Here is my code. I am getting an error 
Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'Byte()'. WindowsApplication2

```
Private Sub Ok_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Ok.Click

Dim DataToEncode As Byte() = txtbox.Text

Dim Base32 As String
Base32 = DataToEncode.ToBase32String()
Auth.Text = Base32
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in `txtbox.Text` is a string which can't be automatically converted to a byte array.  So the line `Dim DataToEncode As Byte() = txtbox.Text` can't be compiled.  To get the ASCII representation of a string use the [`System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
Dim DataToEncode As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtbox.Text)
```

Also strings in VB.Net do not store ASCII values, they use UTF-16.

Comment: Thank you that worked great. I will mark as answer once the seven minute time is up.

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, you're trying to take a string (the context of `txtbox.Text`) and put it in a variable of type `Byte()`, an array of bytes. A string isn't a byte array, it's a logical sequence of *characters* that can have different representation in bytes - do you want to treat it as a UTF-8-encoded string? An ASCII string? A full-blown UTF-32 string? All these are different byte representations of what might be the same textual data.

Once you know the representation you care about, use the [`System.Text.Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx) classes to convert the text to a `Byte()` and pass that to your method.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the string into a byte array using the [`GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Dim DataToEncode As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtbox.Text)
```

Comment: I am now getting an error 'Encoding' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Make sure you have added the proper namespace into scope: `Imports System.Text`. As the documentation I have linked linked into my answer states the `Encoding` class is declared inside the `System.Text` namespace so you should make sure this is available.