# base32 outputting different result

Tags: php, vb.net

The PHP code works no problem whatsoever but when its converted to VB.NET the problems begin. It seems to almost work apart from it suppresses the zero characters from the result. The secret key im using to test this is: BICXYN7ZK5C3WOAP

Im looking for hints not actual code.

vb.net code: http://pastebin.com/P7zhCjXw

output: A57C37C3B95745C2BB38F

php code: http://pastebin.com/qTHmYzwq

output: 0a057c37f95745bb380f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero characters you are referring to is actually padding which is added by PHP.

.NET does not pad the result so you have to do it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried padding and changing the encoding but nothing seems to work https://pastebin.com/Ui3q2s0U

Comment: sorry my rep is low else i'd have commented, but I came across this a couple years back playing with crypto and PHP by design pads the bytes to the length of the buffer. .Net treats '\0' as the end of the string so you need to know the length of the string from the PHP script and size your dictionary to suit prior to filling it with nulls.

Comment: you need to build the result with a list of char rather than a string then create the string after the result

Comment: Thanks for using your time to help me but i think i will just give up.                                https://pastebin.com/WDvaWEXk

Comment: no problem. I did stumble on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159403/ascii-to-base32?rq=1 which provides another hint .Net stores strings as UTF16